# Kivy Popup Error

Tags: python-2.7, popup, kivy

I can't seem to get my popup to open because it is not 'defined'. Everything is passed from the Python to the Kivy language (because it's just easier for me to keep track of everything) and this is the problem spot in question.

```
<StoryScreen>:
name: "story"
BoxLayout:
    id: storyScreen
    Popup:
        id: "popup"
        title: "Settings"
        on_parent: 
            if self.parent == storyScreen: self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Accordion:
                orientation: "vertical"

                AccordionItem:
                    title: "Main Character"
                    size_hint:.9, 0.10
                    pos_hint: {'x':0.05, 'y':0.85}

                    Label: 
                        id: first
                        text: "First Name"

                AccordionItem:
                    title: "Love Interest"
                    size_hint: .9, 0.10
                    pos_hint: {'x':0.05, 'y':0.70}
            Button:
                text: "What's up"
    Button: 
        text: "Press to open popup"
        on_release: popup.open()

    Label: 
        text: "This is a label"
```

My traceback error reads:

```
   File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/lang.py", line 1299, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "./story.kv", line 54, in <module>
     on_release: popup.open()
 NameError: name 'popup' is not defined
```

And even when I tried adding to Python

```
class popup(Popup):
    pass
```

It still throws a definition error. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kv language `id`s are Python identifiers. You can't call a Python variable `"popup"` (because of the quotes), so it's the same with kv. Try using `id: popup` instead of `id: "popup"`.

Comment: It was really that simple. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Well...popup really isn't defined, that's the problem.

You need to get an *instance* of the popup class (e.g. `Popup()`), so you can run something like `Popup().open()`.

That's just for the kivy popup class, for your own subclass you must import it into the kv scope, e.g. `#:import Yourpopupname main.Yourpopupname`, then you can do `Yourpopupname().open()`. I say `yourpopupname` rather than your chosen `popup` because this is a really bad name to choose, it is confusing since it's the same up to capitalisation as kivy's Popup. Also, you should generally use widget names starting with an upper case letter because kv language relies on this to identify them.